# Make LineString resolution depend on level in OpenLayers

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm using OpenLayers to render a `OpenLayers.Geometry.LineString` on a `OpenLayers.Layer.Vector` layer. The idea is that the line, sometimes, can contain a big amount of points, which will make the web browser stall. I can't touch the server code because we retrieve the data from external website.

Is there an elegant way that I can make the line to have less points when you see it in full size, and more points as you zoom to it (increase the line's resolution as you zoom on it)?

The only solutions that I have right now is either to inform the user that the line is humongous and ask him if he has the courage to render it, or to build the line with less points from the start, and risk to have some issues when the user will zoom on the line.

Comment: Can you give an example including line and points?

Comment: In your code,are there only one line or multiple lines ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete solution can be found [here](https://surdu.me/2010/12/20/make-linestring-resolution-depend-on-level-in-openlayers.html).

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that comes to my mind is to handle this manually, ie when you initially get the line geometry from server you create an array that would contain different versions of geometry for every zoom level you need.

So on first position in an array you would have a geometry where you remove say every second point from original geometry. Then on second position every third, fourth and so on...

Then you can listen to OpenLayers.Map zoomend event and show/hide right geometry from your array depending on zoom level.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes. This is the kind of solution I will finally settle on. The problem on your suggestion is that it will take a huge amount of time to initialize. I was thinking to make it like this: make a custom layer that will receive the data and render them according to the level. The drawback is that it will get slower and slower the deeper you go with the zoom level, but if the user will not be interested in zooming (the majority of them), it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

a very quick and dirty solution is to create various layers (representing the route with more or less points) and make each one visible or not according to zoom.

i took this pseudocode from a similar application, where i had direction arrows that i did not want to show when zoom was smaller than 13:

```
vectors1 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector(...);
map.addLayer(vectors1);

// check for zoomLevel
map.events.on({ "zoomend": function (e) {
            if (this.getZoom() < 13) {
                vectors1.setVisibility(false);
            } else {
                vectors1.setVisibility(true);
            }
        }
        });
```